# Is leading '/' before path pattern mistake?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, url, routes

> **URL patterns are expressed without a leading / character, which isn’t part of the URL path.** When the request URL path matches the URL pattern, the request will be forwarded to the endpoint function, which generates the response. (Martin Freeman. Pro ASP.NET Core 3. Page 284. Last paragraph.)

This is told about configuring mapping for EndpointMiddleware by app.UseEndpoint (see example below)

Firstly, why '/' isn't part of the path? HttpContext.Request.Path starts with leading '/'.

Secondly, these code and code using all other patterns with leading '/' works the same as the code without '/'. Is author mistaken or i can't understand something?

```
app.UseEndpoints(rb =>
{
    rb.Map("/{var1}/{*others}", async (ctx) =>
    {
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync($"{ctx.Request.RouteValues["var1"]}");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-template-reference),and after `The following table demonstrates example route templates and their behavior:`,you can see a table.
[image]
`Example Matching URI` in the table are all begins with `/`,so it means matching url all needs to begin with `/`,rather than  the route pattern in the method.

[image]